# Getting the value from the response element using GPath and Rest Assured

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, serenity-bdd, gpath

I want to get the value of `status` from my response. So that i can assert it. I'm using rest assured with java & serenity BDD.

**Response**

```
{
    "locationType": "STORE",
    "locationId": "0003",
    "events": {
        "66e326db-fbfb-4f6e-9d2b-9425e7test5": {
            "status": "BOOKING_OPEN"
        }
    }
}
```

So, here the `event id (66e326db-fbfb-4f6e-9d2b-9425e7test5)` is dynamic, which means for each run this UUID will get change.

**Code**

```
Response response = SerenityRest.lastResponse();
        final ValidatableResponse validatableResponse = response.then();
        validatableResponse.assertThat().body("events.*.status", containsString(expectedResponse));
```

When i run this, i'm getting **Unrecognized Exception** from serenity BDD. I think, that there is some issue in traversing in JSON. 
Can someone please help me on getting the value of status here? So in this case, i'm looking for
**BOOKING_OPEN**

Comment: Doesn't your `body("events")` return you a list of events? Try to iterate them first and reach `status` for each event after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should store UUID as a variable, and change your locator from your response.

```
response.getBody().jsonPath().get("events."+yourUUID+".status");
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy JsonSlurper does not support `*` `breadthFirst()` or `**` `depthFirst()` tokens.

You could use below one to get the String result:

```java
response.getBody().jsonPath().get("events.collect{it.value.status}.find()");
// would return "BOOKING_OPEN"
```

or below one to get a List result:

```java
response.getBody().jsonPath().get("events.collect{it.value.status}");
//would return ["BOOKING_OPEN"]
```